# Not All Cells in TableView showing set font and color

Tags: iphone, xcode, uicolor, uifont

I am trying to get my table view cells to show a certain font and color for each cell.  Using the following code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, most of the cells are showing new color and font, but for some reason there are 2 cells that don't.  Any ideas?

```
CGFloat nRed=204.0/255.0;
   CGFloat nBlue=0/255.0;
   CGFloat nGreen=153.0/255.0;
   UIColor *myColortext=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:nRed green:nBlue blue:nGreen alpha:1];

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"noteworthy" size:15];


    cell.textLabel.text = entry.articleTitle; 


    cell.textLabel.font = cellFont;

   cell.textLabel.textColor = myColortext;
```

Comment: Can you post how you are initializing the cell?

Comment: If I were you, I would set the `font` and `textColor` when I am creating the cell and update only the `text` every time.